# Кнопка назад в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Можно ли как нибудь в этот уже существующий код в верхнем левом углу сделать кнопку назад? Код из активити:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick1(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity4.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void on2k(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Код из layout файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="onClick2"
    android:text="ххх"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="onClick1"
    android:text="ххх"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />
```

Пытался несколькими способами,но надо было изменять активити и layout файлы,что приводило к красным ошибкам,буду благодарен,если кто то поможет.
Скажу проще,нужно чтобы в layout файле появилась кнопка назад,и была возможность манипулировать ей в активити.

Comment: вот тут есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651602/display-back-arrow-on-toolbar

Answer (score 1):

1.Откройте файл `AndroidManifest.xml` Добавьте значение

```
android:parentActivityName=".NameActivity"
```

Например:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity4"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity2">
</activity>
```

2.В файле `MainActivity4.java` добавьте код

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно сделать Тулбар и инициализировать его .

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать Тулбар и инициализировать его

сам xml toolbar можно добавить в разметку как include:

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Далее найти его :

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
```

далее

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolBarSet();//настройки тулбара я выношу обычно

private void toolBarSet() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");

}
```

и повесить на него слушатель в методе таким образом

```
 @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();  //или this.finish или что то свое
    return true;
}
```

активити долно быть `extends AppCompatActivity`